# Entity Framework Non static method needs a target. Null values in Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I'm having a problem in Entity Framework with Lambda Expressions with objects that can be null. I'm doing a Query to search in my Database by some fields, the fields are optionally and if the field is null I do not use it for conditions in the Query and if the field is not null I use it in the Query.

For this I'm trying to do something like this.

```
//Can be null or not
DateTime? date;

//This thorows an Exception "Non Static method needs a target"
List <> data = db.T_USER.Where(U =>
    (date == null || U.JoinDate == date)
).ToList();
```

This code is throwing an Exception "Non static method needs a target"

Searching for solutions here I have found that there are problems with null values in querys so I try to do this. But it also didn't work even if the second par of the OR will never be evaluated because the first part is true.

```
bool DateIsNull = (date == null);

//This thorows an Exception "Non Static method needs a target"
List <> data = db.T_USER.Where(U =>
    (DateIsNull || U.JoinDate == date)
).ToList();
```

My finally solution is this and it works. But this code i think is ugly. Imagine this stupid code for 5 optional fields or more...

```
//Can be null or not
DateTime? date;

bool DateIsNull = (date == null);
DateTime _filterDate = !DateIsNull ? date.Value : DateTime.Now;

List <> data = db.T_USER.Where(U =>
    (DateIsNull || U.JoinDate == _filterDate)
).ToList();
```

Does anyone have a better and more elegant solution for my problem? 
Could someone explain me the details of the reason of throwing the Exception?

Comment: If the parameter is null, why make the DB do all the work? Just omit those where statements. Remember that EF will allow you to do `.Where(...).Where(...)`, so you can use that to build your SQL statement in an efficient way.

Comment: What is you variable name?  You have "List <> ".

Comment: @jdweng. I have corrected my code. It only was an example.

Comment: @ESG, could you explain me the use of multiple .Where() in this situation. I don't understand very well what you want to tell me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I've typically handled this type of scenario is to build the query based on which parameters have values. Something like this:

```
// optional query parameters coming from somewhere...
DateTime? date;
int? age;
string username;

IQueryable<T_USER> query = db.T_USER.AsQueryable();

if(date != null)
    query = query.Where(u => u.JoinDate == date);

if(age != null)
    query = query.Where(u => u.Age == age);

if(username != null)
    query = query.Where(u => u.Username == username);

var results = query.ToList();
```

To me, this is easier to read and it avoids the issue of putting your local expression or variable into the lambda expression that gets passed on to the EF provider.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so this is not valid for me because if I have more than 5 optional parameters I will have to code all the combinations with different parameters. In your answer I can do the following combinations: No parameters, only date, only age, only username, username and age, date and age, username and date .... I think this is a simple solution but you have to code a lot of lambdas for different situations... Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why this solution won't work for you ... Since the query gets "built-up" with each statement and only evaluated and sent to the database at the end - when you call `ToList()` - it can handle multiple combinations of parameters.

Comment: Yes, you are all right, I haven't read well your solution, sorry. You are doing the .Where in multiple steps. Evaluating the parameters outside the EF Query. Thanks for your solution.